# ¿Cómo puedo sumar valores de un campo en MongoDB y almacenar la suma en otro campo?

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, nosql

Mi proyecto necesita una suerte de acumulador que sume una cantidad ingresada y que sume sólo ese valor a otro campo.

Lo estoy desarrollando en `MongoDB` y quiero saber cómo puedo realizarlo en Base de Datos `NoSQL`.

Answer (score 1):

Si el campo esta en el mismo documento simplemente actualiza los 2 campos a la vez con un update.

Pero creo intuir que intentas actualizar otro campo de otro documento, y supongo que necesitas que sea transaccional (ingreso en cuenta bancaria). Mongodb no soporta transacciones fuera del mismo documento, así que lo que tienes que hacer es simular una transacción, por ejemplo, un commit de 2 fases (2PC/2-Phase Commit).

Aquí tienes un ejemplo de como implementarlo con mongodb:

https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/tutorial/perform-two-phase-commits/

**Update:**

Si es el mismo documento, simplemente hay que actualizar los 2 campos del documento, esta operación si es atómica. Ejemplo:

```
db.books.update(
   { _id: 1 },
   {
     $set: {
       item: "ABC123",
       "info.publisher": "2222",
       tags: [ "software" ],
       "ratings.1": { by: "xyz", rating: 3 }
     }
   }
)
```

Si estas utilizando el driver de node:

```
db.collection('updates').updateOne({a:1}, {$set: {b: 1, c: 2}}, function(err, r) {});
```

Comment: Estoy intentando actualizar dos campos del mismo documento. Aunque no estoy del todo seguro, porque cada que genero un registro, según **yo** se perderia la cuenta que llevaba el anterior.